# Triggering a Click Event on an SVG element

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a group of svg nodes that have a `click` event listener attached to them. I also assign a `nodeId` to uniquely identify my different nodes

```
var nodeId = 0;
nodeGroup.append("svg:circle")
    .attr("r", 7)
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .style("stroke", "orange")
    .attr("data-node-id", function(d,i) {
          return nodeId += 1;
     })
    .on('click', nodeInfo);
```

On click, the node triggers a function to display the node object

```
var nodeInfo = function displayNodeInfo(node){
    console.log(node);
}
```

What I am trying to do is invoke this `displayNodeInfo()` function on click of a button separate from the svg group. The function should display either the previous or the next node depending on what was clicked. I figure that `nodeId` would come in handy here.

```
<button id="next-node" />
<button id="previous-node" />

$("#next-node").on("click", function(e){
    displayNodeInfo() //Not sure how to pass the next node here
)};
```

I'm fairly new to D3 and still figuring out its native methods, so I'm just wondering if anyone's had a similar task. Thanks much!

Comment: and what is `nodeGroup`?

Comment: @Anthony just a group of `svg:g` elements

Comment: @KuraiBankusu are the svg:circles data-driven?

Comment: Yes they are @SeemantKulleen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use node index for creating unique id for each node and use the the same for node identification. Should track the index of the present selected node.

```
var activeNodeIndex = 0;

nodeGroup.append("svg:circle")
    .attr("r", 7)
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .style("stroke", "orange")
    .attr("id", function(d,i) {
          return "node"+i; //i has value from 0 to (No. of nodes - 1)
     })
    .on('click', function(node,i){
       activeNodeIndex = i; //Track present selected node.
       displayNodeInfo(node);
    });

function displayNodeInfo(node){
    console.log(node);
}

$("#next-node").on("click", function(e){
   var nextNode  = d3.select("#node"+(activeNodeIndex +1)); //find next node using index
   displayNodeInfo(nextNode);
)};

$("#prev-node").on("click", function(e){    
    var prevNode  = d3.select("#node"+(activeNodeIndex-1));  //find previous node using index
    displayNodeInfo(prevNode);
)};
```

Note:  Enable/disable Next/Prev buttons based on the current node selection(1st OR last).

Comment: This is what I was going for, good use of the index. Thank you very much!