# How do I use javascript to click on this dynamic graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to click on this page: http://www.easycredit-bbl.de/de/n/spielberichte/2016-17/nachbericht/2016-09-23-bam-fra/#specialnavi=34

The page loads with the fourth bar on the graph shaded, and the data on the right reflects that. No matter what I do I can't seem to replicate the manually clicking of the other rectangles in the graph. I've been trying to use some version of this to no luck. I can click other elements on the page through javascript, just not this graph.

```
$($('div.split > div.horizonChart .group rect')[0]).click()
```

I'm not incredibly skilled with JS/html. Any help at all is appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try `.trigger('click')` ?

Comment: Yes, no error but no change on the page at all.

Comment: The graph contains the SVG, which will not be triggered  like HTML DOM

Comment: I think function click is called when graph is not rendered. Where do you put source for displaying graph and source for trigger click?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to what SVG is. Is there any way to click on that? Or generate a click in the area that I need to click that will be registered?

Comment: Read this SO post for an idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35007718/triggering-a-click-event-on-an-svg-element

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to this. It's not my site, I'm just trying to write a script that will enable me to click on the panels in the svg, to trigger the change in HTML. It looks like from the links and what I looked up I need to add an event listener? not sure what that means, but is that on the right track?